# php custom date required

Tags: php, date

i want to make some modification in date but i am not able to do changes dynamically. please examine below example which is might be helpful to understand my code as well requirement

Example :

```
Required Output :
01-01-2014 00:00:00,01-01-2014 00:59:59
01-01-2014 01:00:00,01-01-2014 01:59:59
01-01-2014 02:00:00,01-01-2014 02:59:59
01-01-2014 03:00:00,01-01-2014 03:59:59
01-01-2014 04:00:00,01-01-2014 04:59:59


Code :
 $i=0;
 $start_date = '2013-08-10 11:00:00';
 $min_date=$start_date;
 $current_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
 while (strtotime($min_date) <= strtotime($current_date)) {
 if($i!=0){
   $start_date=date("Y-m-d H",strtotime($start_date)+60*60);
   $start_date.=":00:00";
  }
 $end_date=date("Y-m-d H",strtotime($start_date)).":59:59";
 $min_date=$start_date;
 echo $start_date.",".$end_date."<br>";
 $i++;
}
```

but this is create problem when i wil get start_date from query and just make like dynamic so please give me some suggestions

Example :

```
$start_date = '2013-08-10 11:20:10'; // suppose this date gate from database query


Current Output Of Code :

2013-08-10 11:20:10,2013-08-10 11:59:59

2013-08-10 12:00:00,2013-08-10 12:59:59

2013-08-10 13:00:00,2013-08-10 13:59:59

2013-08-10 14:00:00,2013-08-10 14:59:59



Required Output :

2013-08-10 11:20:10,2013-08-10 12:20:09

2013-08-10 12:20:10,2013-08-10 13:20:09

2013-08-10 13:20:10,2013-08-10 14:20:09

2013-08-10 14:20:10,2013-08-10 15:20:09
```

Comment: You're hard coding `:59:59` into your date but complaining that it's there?! You also have two required outputs that conflict with each other. Which one is the right one?

Comment: yeah i know its hard coding because i can't get any proper solution i have tried my best but not able to do it so just add hard code to make it work but getting difficulty

Comment: Use [mktime](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) to generate desired timestamp, then use [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to format it correctly. To add one hour to timestamp just add 3600 seconds (60s*60m)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solution for me

Code :

```
$start_date='2014-04-16 10:20:10';
$i=0;
$current_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$end_date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($start_date)+(60*60)-1);
while (strtotime($end_date) < strtotime($current_date)) {
if($i!=0){
     $start_date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($start_date)+60*60);
}
$end_date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($start_date)+(60*60)-1);
$min_date=$start_date;
echo $start_date.",".$end_date."<br>";
 $i++;
}
```